# Does Angular2 or Angular4 offer an app state and middleware promise like React / Redux?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, redux, angular2

I used Angular 1 and React / Redux, and one thing I like about React / Redux is that there is a definite app state, and a middleware that can convert a promise into real data.

In Angular 1, we often said, either have some sort of data in the top most controller, or in a parent controller, or by a service object, and people have different opinions, and things go in any direction. There was also no middleware for a promise to be converted to real data, ready to be used by the reducer.

Does Angular2 or Angular4 have something similar or better?

Answer (score -2):

This is a great read, from angular 2 team on how angular 2 handles state storage.

https://www.google.si/search?q=do+you+need+store+angular+2&rlz=1C1AVNE_enSI651SI651&oq=do+you+need+store+angular+2&aqs=chrome..69i57.3536j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

To summarize, you can use ngrx in Angular 2/4 just like you can in redux, react. But you might not need to. Angular 2 offers singleton services, which can do the job of a store just as well. Rember, dependancy injection and services can do a lot of things, like storing data, moving it from component to component, you just have to manage this yourself. Toy with observables and subjects.There is a lot you can do.

But if youre used to the "store", go ahead and include ngrx in your project

I'm not sure what you mean with reducer that converts a promise to real data